# Minimum connection time in Muscat for an Oman Air flight to Paris

Tags: transit, short-connections, mct

I am travelling from Hyderabad (India) to Paris (France) via Muscat and the transit time there is only 2 hours.

Is this sufficient to make the connection?

Answer (score 3):

[If you’re looking to catch a connecting flight, the airport suggests the minimum connection time as 60 minutes for International to International flight, 90 minutes for Domestic to International flights, and 90 minutes for Domestic to Domestic flights.](http://www.layoverguide.com/2014/02/layover-in-muscat-oman.html)

Expect a security screening and x-ray of hand luggage but MCT is a smallish airport and one hour should be quite sufficient.